# React Router doesn't match all optional parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm facing a situation where I have my router working fine with the following configuration:

```
<Route path="/" component={Blog}>
    <Route path="list(/:category)(/:subcat)" component={ArticleList} />
    <Route name="article/:category(/:subcat)/:id" component={ArticlePage} />
</Route>
```

But now I was asked to improve the URL and remove some "unecessary" prefixes from the URLs

**Current URL -> Desired URL**

blog/list/football/worldcup -> blog/football/worldcup

blog/list/football -> blog/football

blog/article/football/10 -> blog/football/10

So I tried unsuccessfully to change my route to keep all parameters optional

```
<Route path="/" component={Blog}>
    <Route path="(/:category)(/:subcat)" component={ArticleList} />
    <Route name=":category(/:subcat)/:id" component={ArticlePage} />
</Route>
```

Is there a way to match the urls as described using react router?

Comment: You can use [`<Redirect />`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#redirect) if you need to keep the current routes but redirect to the simplified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have it like this

```
<Route path="blog" component={Blog}>
  <IndexRoute component={ BlogComponent } />
  <Route path=":category" component={ ArticleCategoryList } />
  <Route path=":category/:subcat" component={ ArticleSubCategoryList } />
</Route>
```

I have prefixed `blog` to the route.

- `IndexRoute` will match **/blog** route, it acts as the index route.
- `:category` will match **blog/football** or **blog/any-sport**
- `:category/:subcat` will match both **blog/football/worldcup** and **blog/football/10**

  You will have to be careful here as this will match for both `subcategory` and `id`.
  You can write a function/middleware which can validate the type of route.. whether id or subcategory.